# How to serve files with rewritten file names?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working on an app which will store images in the file system. For example, if a user uploads an image named "`green.jpg`" it will get stored as **/wwwroot/images/f/c/3/fc3b16ee-9254-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.jpg**

In the database, I will have a table that contains the image name and its original name:

```
UUID                                    Name
fc3b16ee-9254-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64    green.jpg
```

I want the generated html to look like:

```
<img src="/whatever/green.jpg">
```

So the question is how to serve **/wwwroot/images/f/c/3/fc3b16ee-9254-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.jpg** when the browser requests "**green.jpg**" "

Generating **/wwwroot/whatever/green.jpg** is not a good idea because of possible name collisions and supplementary disk io.

What I want is that filenames in the generated HTML to be human readable but store that in a way that I can avoid filename collisions and that there aren't too many files in a directory.

Generating a new directory for each letter of the UUID would solve both problems, but I don't know if it's a good idea.

Using UUID is not important, just the uniqueness of file path is. Even if I use an integer as an unique identifier, if there will be millions of images, having millions of directories might be too much.

If that matters, I am using PostgreSQL as the DB engine and will run the app on Linux. I don't know what filesystem I'll use, probably ext4.

Comment: You can save the files in directory per session, wwwroot/sessionid/whatever/green.jpg

Comment: @ H. Herzl that might mean lots of disk i/o.

Comment: But you can delete the images in sign-out

Comment: It's not about the space taken but you use resources to copy that file. Writing things to disk might slow down the app especially if there are many writing operations waiting to execute.